# Retrieve PayPal history using PayPal PHP SDK

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm asking if it's possible to retrieve users PayPal history by using some PHP SDK. I found in Google and didn't find any helpful information about this, can any give me some starting point? I don't know if using [REST API](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php) I can get this done or I need another SDK like [SDK Core](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php) and examples are not clear for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search transactions using the TransactionSearch API which is part of the Merchant SDK. There's an [example](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/blob/71850935a19437b913d08b0a59e445f50a53b489/samples/AdminCalls/TransactionSearch.php) on how to do it:

```
$transactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType();
$transactionSearchRequest->StartDate = $_REQUEST['startDate'];
$transactionSearchRequest->EndDate = $_REQUEST['endDate'];
$transactionSearchRequest->TransactionID = $_REQUEST['transactionID'];

$tranSearchReq = new TransactionSearchReq();
$tranSearchReq->TransactionSearchRequest = $transactionSearchRequest;

/*
 *       ## Creating service wrapper object
Creating service wrapper object to make API call and loading
Configuration::getAcctAndConfig() returns array that contains credential and config parameters
*/
$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(Configuration::getAcctAndConfig());
try {
    /* wrap API method calls on the service object with a try catch */
    $transactionSearchResponse = $paypalService->TransactionSearch($tranSearchReq);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    include_once("../Error.php");
    exit;
}
if(isset($transactionSearchResponse)) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td>Ack :</td><td><div id='Ack'>$transactionSearchResponse->Ack</div> </td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($transactionSearchResponse);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Take a look at the [API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) for limitations and other variables.